# order of operations: erase old files before building new ones

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Although I though I was pretty good with makefiles, I have a problem I just can't solve about order of commands in a makefile.
Lets detail.

Say I have some program that produces some files of type "a". I want to manually take these and process them through some tool that takes as input one "a" file and produces a file of type "b".

So my makefile holds the following pattern rule:

```
%.b:%.a
   $(MYTOOL) $< >$@
```

I gather all the files to build in a variable `B_FILES`, build from the list of "a" files:

```
A_FILES = $(wildcard *.a)
B_FILES = $(patsubst %.a,%.b,$(A_FILES))
```

And this is called through a general call target:

```
build_b_files: $(B_FILES)
   @echo "done!"
```

Works perfectly.

Now the problem: each run of the main program can generate a varying number of "A" files, with some common naming scheme (say `file_0.a`, `file_1.a`, `file_2.a`, ...).
But if a run produces 20 files, and the following only 10, then I still have the remaining 10 files from latter run present.

So what I want to do is make my `build_b_files` target **automatically erase** all the old "b" file **before** building the new ones.

I tried to use the [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html), but the following fails: it just rebuilds every time all the files, then erases them (!).

```
erase_all_B:
    @rm *.b

build_b_files: $(B_FILES) | erase_all_B
    @echo "- Done target $@"
```

I am probably misunderstanding something about this concept of "order-only".

How can I achieve this goal ?

**Edit**: to clarify question, see the following (simulated) session demonstrating what I am looking for (`ls` only showing relevant files here):

```
$ myapp some-arguments... (will produce 4 'a' files)
$ ls -l            (stripped)
june 8 16:00 file_0.a
june 8 16:00 file_1.a
june 8 16:00 file_2.a
june 8 16:00 file_3.a
$ make build_b_files
$ ls -l
june 8 16:00 file_0.a
june 8 16:00 file_1.a
june 8 16:00 file_2.a
june 8 16:00 file_3.a
june 8 16:00 file_0.b
june 8 16:00 file_1.b
june 8 16:00 file_2.b
june 8 16:00 file_3.b
     .... (some time) ....
$ myapp some-other-arguments... (will produce only 3 'a' files)
$ ls -l
june 8 17:00 file_0.a
june 8 17:00 file_1.a
june 8 17:00 file_2.a
june 8 16:00 file_3.a
june 8 16:00 file_0.b
june 8 16:00 file_1.b
june 8 16:00 file_2.b
june 8 16:00 file_3.b
$ make build_b_files
$ ls -l
june 8 17:00 file_0.a
june 8 17:00 file_1.a
june 8 17:00 file_2.a
june 8 17:00 file_0.b
june 8 17:00 file_1.b
june 8 17:00 file_2.b
```

(For those who wonder, this is about graphviz, that generates images from `dot` files...)

Answer (score 2):

You need to erase all b files before remaking any b files, so what you're saying is that `erase_all_B` should be a prerequisite of the `$(BFILES)` themselves, not `build_b_files`:

```
.PHONY: erase_all_B
erase_all_B: ; $(RM) *.b
$(B_FILES): erase_all_B
```

---

Test with the following

```
all: bar baz
bar baz: foo
ba%:
    @echo bar baz
foo:
    @echo foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried that, but something wrong here, more details to come.

Comment: This does not work. With make 3.81, it seems to replace the dependency of the "B" file on the "A" file (pattern rule) by the dependency on `erase_all_B`. Thus once the "rm" is done, it assumes the file is build, but it nevers calls the pattern rule.

Comment: @kebs Try the minimal test I added, if it works then there's something else wrong with your makefile.

Comment: Thanks for you edit. That seems to work, output is `foo` and twice `bar baz`. I have to investigate to check how this relates to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the tool that produces `.a` files removes the old ones, you can build a "list of `.b` files to remove" easily with something like:

```
TO_REMOVE := $(filter-out $(B_FILES),$(wildcard *.b))
```

And if the tool that produces `.a` files does not remove older ones, why removing matching `.b` files? They will be regenerated, as `.a` files are still here. And if `.a` files are modified, corresponding `.b` files will be regenerated by make (as being out of date).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yeah, this might be a bit unclear in my question. The app that produces the files does not erase anything, it just dumps in the current folder as many files as are needed. But I want only the "new" files to remain after I run my target.

Comment: It looks like you also want make to remove old `.a` files (according to your simulated shell session)?

Comment: Yes, indeed, although it's not mandatory. What I'm interested in is the "B" files, but the problem could be simplified by erasing unwanted "A" files.

Comment: So, why not just `rm *.a *.b` before running the `.a` generator?

Comment: Yep, possible, but I wanted to automate the process afterwards, as this requires issuing a separate command.

Comment: And dropping `myapp` calls in the makefile too? Have you a file target for all this or only multiple `.b` files ?

Comment: The thing is, the app (scientific computations) is designed to be called with varying arguments, so calling it from makefile would not be flexible.

Comment: As the app is responsible to create `.a` files, shouldn't it be responsible of garbage collecting them too? This way the makefile would easily be able to locate orphan `b` files. This way the makefile which creates b files is also responsible to garbage collect them which is consistent?